# Add label for submit button

Tags: cakephp

I'm new in cakephp. What I try to accomplish is this output :

```
<p><label>&nbsp;</label><input class="adminbut rad2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></p>
```

And this is what I did in my view file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array(
'div' => false, 
'label' => 'Login',
'class' => 'adminbut rad2', 
'name' => 'submit', 
'value' => 'Login', 
'before' => '<p>', 
'after' => '</p>'
));?>
```

And what I got is :

```
<input class="adminbut rad2" name="submit" value="Login" type="submit" /></p>
```

And as you can see, my output is missing :

```
<label>&nbsp;</label>
```

Any solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$form->create();

$form->submit("Login",array( 'div' => false,  'class' => 'adminbut rad2',  'name' => 'submit',  'value' => 'Login',  'before' => '<p><label>&nbsp;</label>',  'after'
=> '</p>'

));

$form->end();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $form->input('submit', array(
    'type'=>'submit', 
    'value'=>'Login', 
    'class'=>'adminbut rad2',
    'div'=>array('tag'=>'p'),
    'label'=>"&nbsp;"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This my friend
Cakephp 2.X

```
$this->Form->submit(__('Submit'), array('class'=>'adminbut rad2'));
```

Cakephp 1.x

```
$form->submit(__('Submit'), array('class'=>'adminbut rad2'));
```